# 搞得头 ，弄得头 ，睡过头 what does mean 头 in these three examples?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning

What does 头 in 搞得头 / 弄得头 / 睡过头

For example in this sentence:
可是这个密码那个密码，搞得头都大了。

“头” 是 head的意思？
“头” 字是个结果补语还是名词？

Comment: 頭大, big head, means headache.

Comment: Top, as in "over the top"

Answer (score 3):

To extend the answer from @r13:

These two following '头' refer to 'a person's head':
搞(弄)得头都大了 - something causes my head swollen(meaning you are headache).
搞(弄)得头都暈了 - something causes my head dizziness/confusion.

In last case, 头 is not 'head':
There are several dialects call '小时-hour(Mandarin)' as '钟头' or '中午-noon' as '中午头', but they will be commonly understood by most of Chinese. I'm not sure 'hour' or 'noon' which one exactly referring to, just remember it's related to time.
So, 睡过头 - means 'sleep pass the hour' or 'sleep pass the noon', oversleep

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Comment: @DrewYang are you saying  睡过头 is derived from something like 睡过钟头? That's interesting.

Answer (score 2):

搞(弄)得头都大了 - something causes headache.

搞(弄)得头都暈了 - something causes dizziness/confusion.

睡过头 - overslept

Answer (score 2):

There are two things happening here. In your example, 可是这个密码那个密码，搞得头都大了, the second half should be parsed as: (搞得)+(头都大了).

It's the same for 弄; see the examples in r13's answer.

Basically, 搞得头 and 弄得头 are not a single grammatical entity.

"头都大了" is an interesting phrase that's worth looking at. I find it a bit hard to translate, my best attempt is "already has a headache". As far as I understand (I may be wrong), it is derived from a) "头大" which is a dialectal word (方言) according to dictionaries; and b) the structure " 都 + predicate + 了 = 已经 + predicate = already + predicate".

"头都暈了", mentioned in other answers, follows the same pattern. ("already dizzy")

The second case is 睡过头 which is a fixed expression that is in dictionaries and means to oversleep.

Comment: Thanks, in this case if 头大 means headache what for 都 is in middle of 头都大？

Comment: Good question! With the 了, here the 都 means "already", it's another structure: 都 +predicate+了 = 已经 + predicate = already + predicate . (Disclaimer, I'm not an expert, I may be mistaken. )  I think I'll edit my answer tomorrow, I now think it should be parsed as (搞得)+(头都大了).

Comment: thank you for your comment!